# Bash - move cursor to a line not visible in the window

Tags: bash, ansi-escape

I'm trying to write a command that writes many lines of output, then rewinds to the beginning to overwrite them in sequence with more information. To do this, I count the number of lines, then move that many lines up with ANSI escape codes, then start outputting again. This works great if the many lines of output fit in the window I have open, but if there are too many lines, the cursor only ends up moving to the top visible line. How can I always go back to the beginning of the output, regardless of the window size?

Comment: You need some tool that implements a virtual buffer; ANSI escape codes only work on the *actual* terminal, which only deals with visible lines. Further, `bash` doesn't know anything about number lines; it just writes to a file, one line after another.

Comment: Quick and simple is: ANSI CSI (ESC + '[') + 'H' {as in HOME}.
(C/Bash): "\033[H"

Answer (score 0):

One simpler option may be to use a library to do it instead of doing all the heavy lifting and calculations yourself have a look at something like [BashSimpleCurses](https://github.com/metal3d/bashsimplecurses) this would allow you to use the update function easily.

Comment: I'm running on my institution's servers, so I don't think I'm able to install outside packages... but lemme take a look and try this out.